# Display query results in WPF Datagrid simplest way

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

hi i tried the below code but not working to diaply query results on WPF data grid., any inpus pls.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    string queryString = "select * from dob.table_1";
    sqlConn.Open();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sqlConn);
    a.Fill(table);

    this.datagird1.DataContext = table;
}
```

Datagrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1"
Height="219" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="datagird1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
Width="499" AllowDrop="True" />
```

Comment: on Datagrid empty rows are shown.

Comment: Have you considered using a LINQ to SQL DataClasses object?  They are very easy to work with and manage all the querying behind the scenes.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is set to false. So from where on Earth do you expect columns to appear?

Answer (score 2):

This is 3 years too late, but good for other people that arrive here via google.
Please have a look at this example, this is exactly what you need:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/362436/Data-binding-in-WPF-DataGrid-control

Comment: Please provide some content for your provided link according to the [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) rules. At least a short summary about the solution strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView
```

you should also change AutoGenerateColumns to "TRUE"

```
AutoGenerateColumns="TRUE"
```

It should work.
you can read about this attribute here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx

You can also see step by step in the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

Comment: <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Height="219" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="datagird1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499" AllowDrop="True" />

Answer (score 0):

try this, its working for me :

```
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FCT_P155_30920", _cnn);

        //fill the DataTable
        dAdapter.Fill(dTable);

        //set the DataGridView DataSource
        dgPrograms.ItemsSource = dTable.AsDataView();
```