# WPF Datagrid does not dispay all values

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have SQL table like this,

```
 Name   |   03.04.2013   |   05.04.2013   |  07.03.2013  |  09.04.2013 
--------|----------------|----------------|--------------|---------------
```

I want to display this table in a datagrid.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Fee", sc2);


DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

datagrid2.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

When I tried it, the datagrid only shows names, and the values from date columns are empty.(`AutoGenerateColumns="true"`)

I added mainwindows.xaml source [here](http://snipt.org/Athd9) and xaml code [here](http://snipt.org/Athe1)

Comment: It's caused by the dots in the columnname. With AutoGenerateColumns="false", you'd explicitly define the Path of the Binding to be 03.04.2013, being the 2013 property of the 04 property of the 03 value. Giving the columnnames an alias without a dot solves it, but I'd like see a better solution as well.

Comment: but it was working yesterday before i did make some changes

Comment: I guess there is no better solution.I changed dots with "-"  it seems problem solved thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Fee", sc2);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "DataGridBind");
        datagrid2.DataContext = ds;
```

In Xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridBind}">
```

Comment: Still same problem,it doesn't make any sense it was working yesterday,i did some changes then this happened

Comment: do you have any records in Fee Table?

Comment: Yes it includes int values

Comment: Maybe you changed connection string

Comment: PLease include xaml and xaml.cs code as well. So I can tell what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try with..

```
string ConString = "Use your database address";
string CmdString = string.Empty;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    CmdString = "SELECT * FROM Fee";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Fee");
    sda.Fill(dt);
    datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
 }
```

Also can view..

- [Display query results in WPF Datagrid simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200165/display-query-results-in-wpf-datagrid-simplest-way)
- http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/34103-WPF-Binding-DataTable-WPF-Datagrid.aspx

Comment: My question was about WPF i cant use datagridview1.Datasource and datagridview.Readonly

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the AutoGenerateColumns to False and add the bindings to custom columns:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>                    
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=NAME}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Path=AGE}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=DATE}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

With this you can also create a converter class that extends IValueConverter to put some sort of a mask in your data.

Comment: In program user add column.Wouldn't be so hard to bind more than 50 columns